# Trying to make the button onclick access an API Url link

Tags: javascript

Im creating a news app project that pulls JSON data from an API.

The API library provides a link to the "full story."

How do I change the address of window.open() when the url is essentially an array location within a JSON file?

Heres my solution thus far

HTML

```
 <button onclick="newWindow()">Click for full story</button>
```

JavaScript

```
 function newWindow(){
  window.open(data.news[0].url)
   }
```

JSON

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "news": [
    {
      "id": "4e6",
      "title": "Soccer team wins the World Cup"
      "url": "wwww.newsnetwork.com/soccer-team-wins-the-world-cup"
...
```

Comment: You need to use AJAX to read the JSON file. Parse it with `JSON.parse()`, then access the array element.

Comment: what do you mean change the address in the address bar? could you provide more context?  where do you get `data` ? what is the desired behaviour? meaning the scenario you want to happen step by step

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript's built in function [**fetch**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), to get what your api is sending back. After that you have to make it into a object(JSON) to access it's properties.

Note: Don't forget to handle errors in case the api isn't working or you url is missing, you can do all that in the **.catch**

```
function newWindow() {
        fetch("http://example.com/movies.json")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            window.open(data.news[0].url);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error("oops:",error));
    }
```

Comment: adding context to your answer will help OP understand your solution better rather than just pasting a blob of code with no explanation